# Ansible: no password in log for community.docker.docker_container env-vars

Tags: security, docker, ansible, environment-variables

Via ansible (AWX) I start a docker container with the `community.docker.docker_container` module. I have some environment variables that I dont wat to be logged. Here is a small example:

```
    - name: "Run Container"
      community.docker.docker_container:
        name: "test_{{ container_name | string}}"
        image: "{{ docker_image }}"
        cleanup: "{{ cleanup_container }}"
        detach: true
        volumes:
          - /data/Docker/test/model:/data/model
        env:
          SECRET1: !vault |
            $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
            23858239t6923858239t699396923858239t6993969348634869323858239t699396934869693486
          SECRET2: !vault |
            $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
            294867829692758795478584885874659294867829692758795478584885874659
          Not_a_seceret: 42
        networks:
          - name: "test"
    #   no_log: true
```

Of course I can use the `no_log: true` option, but this way I loose all information on this step and not only the environment variables, so this would be a plan B and now I am looking for a plan A.
And there are similar [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/681832/how-can-i-stop-ansible-from-writing-passwords-to-the-logfiles) but these are not concerned with the `community.docker.docker_container` module.

Is there a way to only hide the secret env-vars in the log fine?

Comment: The module is open source, you can submit a PR to change the behavior of the module to accomplish what you're looking for.